# Anticyclotomic character

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $E$ be a CM field and $\mathfrak{p}$ a prime in $E$ non-split in the extension $E/E^{+}$. Does there exist an interger $r_{E}$ such that for any integer $r \geq r_{E}$, there exists a finite order anticyclotomic character over $E$ with conductor $\mathfrak{p}^{r}$?

Comment: Isn't this false if $\mathfrak{p}$ is split in $E / E^+$, where $E$ is the totally real subfield, as the conductor of an anticyclotomic character must be preserved by $\operatorname{Gal}(E / E^+)$?

Comment: Thanks. The question is corrected accordingly. Is the answer affirmative in the above form?

Comment: It's still false. Take $E = \mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{-1})$, $r = 1$ and $\mathfrak{p}$ the unique prime above 2.

Comment: Will you please offer some details? Can the existence be expected under mild hypotheses?

Comment: The ray class group of $E$ modulo $\mathfrak{p}^r$ is trivial for $r \le 3$, as is easily seen, so there are no nontrivial finite-order Hecke characters of conductor dividing $\mathfrak{p}^3$ (anticyclotomic or otherwise).

Comment: The edited question looks more reasonable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34843/discussion-between-david-loeffler-and-hhh1).